# Angular JS Object in knockout JS

Tags: angularjs, knockout.js

I want to use the angular js object in knockout js and bind the data to the view on knockout.

Ex : I can get the angular js object as

```
jQuery('#ng-app').data('$scope')
```

But this will return all the scope variable. Now I want to get a specific object from this object, say a userDetails object. SO I can get the object in browser console with :

```
jQuery('#ng-app').data('$scope').userDetails
```

I want the same to use in my knockout js viewmodal and then bind the values to my view fields.

Comment: You are probably better off just picking one framework rather than clumsily trying to make them work together. But if you must, `userDetails` is just a JS object. You could be able to map it to a knockout view model.

Comment: Use the [mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin.

Comment: The documentation contains a bunch of examples and you can always search the internet for more.

Comment: Thanks @MattBurland, how ever I posted this question after doing a lot of searching on the internet.

Comment: Then what part are you stuck on? Using the mapping plugin is as simple as `var myVM = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);` What part is causing you problems? Because you currently don't have enough detail for any answer beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

Although both Angular JS and KO implement MVVM, they do it in a differnt way.

In particular, in KO, to be able to do "live binding", you need the properties to be observables. I.e. if the original object is like this:

```
var vm = {
  name: 'John'
}
```

You can bind it to a KO view. However, after doing so, if you change the value of name, the view won't be refreshed (and changing the value in the view, won't update the property in the viewmodel). If you need this to happen, you must have an object like this:

```
var vm = {
  name: ko.observable('John')
};
```

The fastest way to covnert a regular JS object to an object with ko observable properties is by using [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin.